# cannot open url made by using rails server on cloud9IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanna open the url made by using rails server on cloud9IDE.So i try `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` to run, and rails server is running, but when open url `http://tcp://0.0.0.0:8080`, the server cannot detected.

Could you help me?

```
$ rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

[not detected img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv5ll.png)

Comment: Which URL did you click?

Comment: oh,,,sorry.I changed.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Still asking: which URL did you open? The screenshot shows something strange

Comment: I can't open the url [http://tcp://localhost:8080] .When successes rails server by [rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080] , so next try to open the url made [http://tcp://0.0.0.0:8080] .But not detected the url.Why?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open, literally, `http://tcp://0.0.0.0:8000`. That's not a valid URL since it specifies two protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), so the way it works is a bit different than developing locally on your machine.
For example when run the server, it won't be possible to access it through `localhost:3000`. Instead Cloud9 will provide you with the link to see the running application, this link should normally pop-up when you run the server, but if not, then you can click on `preview` which you find in the upper menu (check the image below) and then `preview running application`

[image]

Comment: Upper menu was hidden ! But I could find preview running application. Thank you!